# How to serialize a string into JSON and group by one of the values?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am currently serialising a datatable using JsonConvert().SerialiseObject(dt) into a JSON format that looks something like
`{"id": "123", "name": "xyz", "value": "a"},{"id": "234", "name": "xyz", "value": "a"},{"id": "789, "name": "x", "value": "b"}` etc

I would like the format to be grouped by the value for example:-

```
[
   {
      "value":"a",
      "members":[
         {
            "id":"123",
            "name":"xyz"
         },
         {
            "id":"234",
            "name":"xyz"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "value":"b",
      "members":[
         {
            "id":"789",
            "name":"x"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

is this easy to achieve with newtonsoft?

Comment: Newtonsoft is good to serialize / deserialize objects. You should create the desired structure as C# class, fill it from your data (AutoMapper is good tool to traverse data between different C# classes) and then serialize it with Newtonsoft. A serializer is not the best tool to re-structure your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would preferably get your data in the required format before serialization.
Something like this for example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;

var dataTable = new[]
{
    new { Id = 123, Name = "xyz", value = "a" },
    new { Id = 123, Name = "xyz", value = "a" },
    new { Id = 123, Name = "xyz", value = "b" },
};

var groupedByValue = dataTable
    .GroupBy(x => x.value)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Value = x.Key,
        Members = x.Select(m => new
        {
            m.Id,
            m.Name
        })
    });

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(groupedByValue);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Comment: This is a beautifully simple solution, thank you! I did try to group by value in the sql but the serialisation came out flat either way